# Framebuffer Imageviewer on Ubuntu 12.04.2 virtual machine

Tags: 12.04, vmware, framebuffer

I'm trying to view some jpg's on my Ubuntu VMWare server using fbi but I'm getting "/dev/fb0: No such file or directory", which is valid since it doesn't exist.  Using hwinfo --frambuffer it lists the VESA Framebuffer.  Is there a way to use this to display the jpg's?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the manpage for `fbi`

```
This program displays images using the Linux framebuffer device.
```

The proprietary graphics drivers won't use the traditional framebuffer device. There is [fbgrab](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/fbgrab), which allows you to specify the device to capture from, but you'd still need to know the device name e.g. /dev/[device]